# Find multiple characters in a array of python

Tags: python, arrays

I have a simple array like this

```
x=[0,0,0,1,1,1,2]
```

I would like to know, the number `1` is in what index.
So far, when I am doing this:

```
a = ["a", "b", "b", "d", "e"]
print(a.index("b"))
```

from the code above the result is `1`, is there a way to get the result that `1` is in index `1` and `2`

Comment: How do your `x` and `a` lists relate to each other? It's not quite clear.

Comment: `[i for i,val in enumerate(a) if val=='b']`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding the index of an item in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176918/finding-the-index-of-an-item-in-a-list)

Comment: @AKX I am sorry, ```x``` and ```a``` are 2 different example. so in ```x``` I would like to find index for ```1``` and for list of ```a``` I would like to find index of ```b```

Comment: @sushanth I just take a look to the link that you have given, and yes.. that question is related to my case and I also found answer there, thank you very much...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @waveshaper suggested one way of doing it can be,

```
x=[0,0,0,1,1,1,2]
a=x;
print([i for i,val in enumerate(a) if val==1])
```

output:

```
[3, 4, 5]
```

It returns a list of index values where your data is present and in this case data is `1`

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out in the comments, a linear approach for random data uses [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) and a [comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
a = ["a", "b", "b", "d", "e"]

b_indeces = [i for i, v in enumerate(a) if v == "b"]
# [1, 2]
```

You can do better, however, if the data is sorted (as in the given examples), using [`bisect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html) to find the left and right boundaries of the index range:

```
from bisect import bisect, bisect_left

b_indeces = list(range(bisect_left(a, "b"), bisect(a, "b")))
# [1, 2]
```